# Using qooxdoo desktop without having to "build" it

Tags: qooxdoo

in qooxdoo desktop you usually have to develop using the SDK and then "build" your app.

Is there a way to generate something like a qooxdoo.js file with the whole library inside so that you can script script it as you like (like jqueryui or dojo)?
Actually it could be nice to have every widget loaded at runtime like dojo's require("dojo.button") but both the approaches would be nice, just avoiding the build phase.

I hope the question is understandable :)
Thank you everybody!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the output of the *build* job to run your code as you develop - as among other things - will minify your code and make debugging very difficult.

If you want to code freely without needing to rebuild when you reference new classes then *source-all* is the build job for you.

In the root directory of your application, type:

```
python generate.py source-all
```

If will include the entire framework in the HTML file generated (you'll find it under source/index.html). This would work well if you are composing the UI from scratch and referencing many new qooxdoo widgets with each browser refresh.

If you add a completely new class of your own, you will need to run the *source-all* job again to include it.

I use the *source* build job however for a few reasons:

- **Habit**: source-all didn't exist when I started using qooxdoo
- **Speed**: You can notice a bit of lag it when you refresh the browser to view
  your app
- **References**: For a mature app, enough of the framework is
  included in the application and its rare to add a new reference and
  when you do, its probably in a new class of your own which would
  require a re-run of the source job anyway.

I suggest you also look at [Default Action Jobs](http://manual.qooxdoo.org/3.5/pages/tool/generator/default_jobs_actions.html) as all the possibilities are explained in detail. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Please check that thread for a detailed answer: http://qooxdoo.678.n2.nabble.com/Using-qooxdoo-desktop-without-having-to-build-it-td7585015.html;cid=1387453759247-228